# XSL: Trouble with Sibling Axis. Is position() the answer?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have xml that approximates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <num>Book 1.</num>
    <head> Title</head>
    <chapter>
        <num>1.</num>
        <head> The Begining</head>
        <p>content</p>
    </chapter>
    <num>12. </num><p>we want that number untouched</p>
    <chapter>
        <num>2.</num>
        <head> The Middle</head>
        <p>content</p>
    </chapter>
    <head>Heads Occur</head><p>we want that head untouched</p>
</book>
```

Where a `<num>` is followed immediately by a `<head>` I want to merge the two together. I use this xsl, with some success, but not in all use-cases.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="num[following-sibling::head]">
        <mergedhead>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::head"/>
        </mergedhead>    
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- keep the old head from showing up in the new output-->
    <xsl:template match="head[preceding-sibling::num]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`following::sibling` and `preceding::sibling` work, but not in all use-cases. Sometimes they pull in `<num>` and `<head>` that are not directly next to each other. Output of my flawed XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <mergedhead>Book 1. Title</mergedhead>
    <chapter>
        <mergedhead>1. The Begining</mergedhead>
        <p>content</p>
    </chapter>
    <mergedhead>12. Heads Occur</mergedhead><p>we want that number untouched</p>
    <chapter>
        <mergedhead>2. The Middle</mergedhead>
        <p>content</p>
    </chapter>
    <p>we want that head untouched</p>
</book>
```

You can see that it merged the #12, which I want untouched, with the 'heads occur' which I also want untouched. I know it's because they are siblings, even there are other nodes in between. I think the answer I want is in `position()`. But I have not been successful with that.

For reference, the desired out is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <mergedhead>Book 1. Title</mergedhead>
    <chapter>
        <mergedhead>1. The Begining</mergedhead>
        <p>content</p>
    </chapter>
    <num>12. </num><p>we want that number untouched</p>
    <chapter>
        <mergedhead>2. The Middle</mergedhead>
        <p>content</p>
    </chapter>
    <head>Heads Occur</head><p>we want that head untouched</p>
</book>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following xslt if it fulfils your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Take all following sibling elements (i.e. following-sibling:*) regardless their names, from them take first one (i.e. [1]) and test it if it is head (i.e. [self::head]-->
    <xsl:template match="num[following-sibling::*[1][self::head]]">
        <mergedhead>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            <!-- Take the first following sibling -->
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::head[1]"/>
        </mergedhead>    
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- similar to num template -->
    <xsl:template match="head[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::num]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It did the trick. I'll have to study to learn from it. I had never used the SELF axis before, and I always wondered how it might be used. Now I know. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to check the XPath spec in [section 2.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates) : "A predicate filters a node-set with respect to an axis to produce a new node-set. For each node in the node-set to be filtered, the PredicateExpr is evaluated with that node as the context node". What is important here is that the node tested becomes the context node, thus `self` refers to the current sibling considered.